# File "delete" option missing from Sense/Net7

Tags: c#, sensenet, sense

I have installed Sense / Net Following the guide shown in:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=640NYCFRuLk

the web works fine, I have uploaded a couple of files to the server, but the option to delete files does not appear to me, I have seen that it should appear in the "Actions" menu, but it does not appear.
[Action menu options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cTCNp.png)

I've also looked at "Apps", where the option should appear and I can't find it.
[Image of Apps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WKwEf.png)

Another Photo of the missing option:
[drop down options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yDGdE.png)

I am acting with the Admin user, and in the directories I have all the permissions
[Photo of permissions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eq6hG.png)

**Updated**: in Apps the folder Generic Content Dont appear, so i cant go to GenericContent/delete to see the permissions
[Photo of missing Folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/THT3x.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED**: Reinstall sense / Net and the options already appear, it had to be a problem in the installation of the Database.

Answer (score 0):

The action that you are looking for is here:

[image]

Or if you want to delete multiple content at once, than you find the delete action in the toolbar

[image]

Comment: I already looked for it there too, I don't see the option, I update post so you can see that

Comment: @FranGarciaCastillo Can you please also attach a screenshot about the setpermissions action's page?

Comment: @FranGarciaCastillo you've attach an image with the permissions on the /Root/Global folder but you are searching for the delete on the /Root/BDDocumentos/Folder. Can you please attach the setpermisson screen of the mentioned folder?

Comment: updated photo, but it has all the permissions and still does not appear

Comment: Can please you check /Root/(apps)/GenericContent/Delete and its SetPermission page if the Administrators groups has full access on this action?

Comment: Maybe the problem is here, I don't see the folder "Generic Content",  and by url also does not access, the folder is not

Comment: What is the error message, when you try to open the GenericContent folder by url? Does it say 'access denied' or 404?

Comment: I mean if you try the url https://${yoursite.com}/Root/(apps)/GenericContent in the browser

Comment: Ok, I've reached the url and got into the Delete folder and the admin permissions are correct, all allowed. The problem is elsewhere then

Comment: Can I reach your sensenet instance somehow? Does it have a public url? I would try to login and see what the problem might be

Comment: Hopefully, but I don't have permission to do that... Im working in a intranet